# Ubuntu 16.04 freeze when connecting to wireless network after starting docker daemon

Tags: networking, docker, ubuntu-16.04

System Environment:
 1. Ubuntu 16.04.2 kernel 4.8.0
 2. docker version 1.13.1
 3. usb wireless driver rtl8192cu
 4. There is a wired network already. It's working properly.

Problem:
After I first start docker daemon with `service docker start`, If I use the network manager to connect a wireless network, the whole desktop freeze. I can't do anything but hard restart the computer.
However, if I first stop the docker daemon, and then connect a wireless network, and then restart the docker daemon, no freezing this time.

Question:
Is this a problem with the bridge network of docker? What can I do with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This could be similar to [issue 20401](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20401)

> the device mapper is stuck in an infinite “mount/remount” loop

Check after your hard reboot for the content of `/var/log/upstart/docker.log`.
Also try and start the docker daemon with the `--debug=true` flag to have more clues.
Also:

> check if you have the option `MountFlags=slave` in `docker.service` file or not. If it is there, that means docker daemon will start in a separate mount namespace with slave relationship from parent.